# Search Dropdown in react js

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I have created the dropdown search in react JS but I want to access the value in options so that I can pass this value to a filterData function and do some operations on it.

Drop down contents:

```
const options = [
    { value: 'Argentina', label: 'Argentina' },
    { value: 'Belize', label: 'Belize' },
    { value: 'Bermuda', label: 'Bermuda' },
    { value: 'Bolivia', label: 'Bolivia' },
    { value: 'Bonaire', label: 'Bonaire' },
    { value: 'Brazil', label: 'Brazil' },
    { value: 'Canada', label: 'Canada' },
    { value: 'Chile', label: 'Chile' },
    { value: 'Colombia', label: 'Colombia' },
    { value: 'Costa Rica', label: 'Costa Rica' },
    { value: 'Curazao', label: 'Curazao' },
    { value: 'Dominican Republic', label: 'Dominican Republic' },
    { value: 'Ecuador', label: 'Ecuador' },
    { value: 'El Salvador', label: 'El Salvador' },
    { value: 'Guatemala', label: 'Guatemala' },
    { value: 'Honduras', label: 'Honduras' },
    { value: 'Jamaica', label: 'Jamaica' },
    { value: 'Mexico', label: 'Mexico' },
    { value: 'Nicaragua', label: 'Nicaragua' },
    { value: 'Panama', label: 'Bermuda' },
    { value: 'Paraguay', label: 'Paraguay' },
    { value: 'Peru', label: 'Peru' },
    { value: 'Puerto Rico', label: 'Paraguay' },
    { value: 'Russia', label: 'Russia' },
    { value: 'Spain', label: 'Spain' },
    { value: 'Switzerland', label: 'Switzerland' },
    { value: 'Trinidad and Tobago', label: 'Trinidad and Tobago' },
    { value: 'US', label: 'US' },
    { value: 'Uruguay', label: 'Uruguay' },
    { value: 'Venezuela', label: 'Venezuela' }
];
```

Inside of the class:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {    
         selectedOption: null
    };

     this.showDropdownMenu = this.showDropdownMenu.bind(this);
     this.hideDropdownMenu = this.hideDropdownMenu.bind(this);
     this.DropdownMenu = this.DropdownMenu.bind(this);
     this.OnClick = this.FilterData.bind(this);
     this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  };


handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
             this.setState({ selectedOption });
             console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
                  };


FilterData (a) {
    // debugger;
    console.log(a);
  }

    render() {
        const { selectedOption } = this.state;
        var textStyle = {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '50%',
            left: '50%'
        };
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={textStyle} className="dropdown" style={{ background: 'white', width: '200px' }}>
                    <Select
                        value={selectedOption}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        options={options}
                        onClick={this.FilterData(selectedOption)}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I tried the following code but it gives undefined value:

```
    FilterData(a) {
        console.log(options.value);
    }
```

I wanted to access the "value" from "options" so that I can pass onto the filterData function.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving `Event` in your state, not the element. To get the value, try this instead:

```
FilterData(a) {
    console.log(a.target.value);
}
```

Alternatively, change the code where you set the state:

```
handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption.target });
};
```

This is the better option

Comment: The answer is     this.state = {    
         selectedOption: {}
    }; while doing this it is able to access the value.